# Keybindings randomly stop working because of losing focus maybe?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keylistener, key-bindings

I know I posted previous questions on this topic, but I am posting a new one here because I created the MCVE that I needed. Here is the class that can reproduce the problem (if you copy and paste this code into your Java editor (but changing the package name), then it will be able to startup succesfully without problems. This is a full test program):

```
package com.blockhead7360.test.ppa;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class TotalKeyTest {

static JTextArea area;

static int i = 0;

public TotalKeyTest(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 600));

    JComponent comp = (JComponent) frame.getContentPane();
    frame.getRootPane().getRootPane().setActionMap(bindKeys(comp).getActionMap());
    frame.getRootPane().getRootPane().setInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, bindKeys(comp).getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);         

}

public static JComponent bindKeys(JComponent comp){
    comp.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed SPACE"), "pressSpace");
    comp.getActionMap().put("pressSpace", new AbstractAction(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("pressed Space");
        }
    });

    comp.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed A"), "pressLeft");
    comp.getActionMap().put("pressLeft", new AbstractAction(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("pressed left");
        }
    });
    comp.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released A"), "releaseLeft");
    comp.getActionMap().put("releaseLeft", new AbstractAction(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("released left");
        }
    });

    comp.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "pressRight");
    comp.getActionMap().put("pressRight", new AbstractAction(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("pressed right");
        }
    });
    comp.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released D"), "releaseRight");
    comp.getActionMap().put("releaseRight", new AbstractAction(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("released right");
        }
    });
    return comp;

}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new TotalKeyTest();
}

}
```

If you would like it as a pastebin, here it is: http://pastebin.com/EhPJeAPC

Basically, what happens is when I press the SPACE, A, and D keys a few times at the beginning (short AND long presses), it works. After a few more short and long presses, it just stops working!

Can someone help?

EDIT: BTW I know that the code includes the frame.getRootPane() instead of just using frame.add(), but this was there because I was trying some stuff out. I can change it back if you want.

EDIT: I found out that it works perfectly fine if I use the arrow keys instead of the A and D keys. I don't know why, but I'm gonna roll with it.

Comment: (1-) And what happens when you test the working code that was given to you in your previous question??? Why do you expect us to debug your code when you have already been given working code? So instead of us taking time to test your code. You take the time to test our code. If our code doesn't work then maybe there is a version/ platform issue.

Comment: `I found out that it works perfectly fine if I use the arrow keys` - how did you find that out? Did you finally test the code given to you previously?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the wrong input map for the contentPane. You're using the default `getInputMap()` which uses the default `JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED` map, when you should be using the more specific `getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)`

For example, my MCVE:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TotalKeyTest2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
    private InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
    private ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

    public TotalKeyTest2() {
        setBindings();
    }

    private void setBindings() {        
        insertKey(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, "Space");
        insertKey(KeyEvent.VK_A, "Left");
        insertKey(KeyEvent.VK_D, "Right");
    }

    private void insertKey(int keyCode, String text) {
        KeyStroke pressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, false);
        KeyStroke released = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, true);
        String pressedActionName = text + " Pressed";
        String releasedActionName = text + " Released";
        Action pressedAction = new MyAction(pressedActionName);
        Action releasedAction = new MyAction(releasedActionName);        
        inputMap.put(pressed, pressedActionName);
        inputMap.put(released, releasedActionName);
        actionMap.put(pressedActionName, pressedAction);
        actionMap.put(releasedActionName, releasedAction);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class MyAction extends AbstractAction {

        public MyAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(getValue(NAME));
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TotalKeyTest2 mainPanel = new TotalKeyTest2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TotalKeyTest2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Blockhead7360: what happens when you try the code above?

Comment: It still does the same thing. It works at first, but after I start to long press the keys or press them faster, it eventually stops sending the debug messages when I press the keys.

Comment: I also tried updating my JDK just in case it might work, but it didn't

Comment: Hmm... It turns out that it must be something with the type of key. I used the LEFT, RIGHT, and SPACE keys instead of A, D, and SPACE and now it works! I'll just roll with it. Thanks though!

Comment: @Blockhead7360: do you have other components added to your GUI, components that already have mappings for those keys?